# ejs Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%-"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, template-engine

I am unsure why I am getting this error. My ejs "include" syntax looks right, and I believe I entered the file paths the proper way. I looked at old stackoverflow posts and came up empty. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%-".
    at /Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:710:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Template.generateSource (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:700:15)
    at Template.compile (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:554:12)
    at Object.compile (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:368:16)
    at handleCache (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:216:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:255:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:461:10)
    at View.render (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
```

---

**here is my index.js file**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = new express()
const ejs = require('ejs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.set('views', '/Users/lorenzi/Desktop/startbootstrap-clean-blog/views');


app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('App listening on port 4000 ...')    
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index');
});

app.get('/about',(req,res)=>{    
    res.render('about');
})

app.get('/contact',(req,res)=>{        
    res.render('contact');
})

app.get('/post',(req,res)=>{    
    res.render('post')
})
```

---

**here is my main include statement from my index.ejs file**

```
  <%- include('layouts/header'); -%>

  <%- include('layouts/navbar'); -%>

<%- include('layouts/footer'); -%> 

  <%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%>
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <%- include('layouts/header'); -%>

<body>

  <%- include('layouts/navbar'); -%>


  <!-- Page Header -->
  <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="post.html">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
              Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up
            </h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            on September 24, 2019</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="post.html">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              I believe every human has a finite number of heartbeats. I don't intend to waste any of mine.
            </h2>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            on September 18, 2019</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="post.html">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              Science has not yet mastered prophecy
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
              We predict too much for the next year and yet far too little for the next ten.
            </h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            on August 24, 2019</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="post.html">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              Failure is not an option
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
              Many say exploration is part of our destiny, but it’s actually our duty to future generations.
            </h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            on July 8, 2019</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- Pager -->
        <div class="clearfix">
          <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <%- include('layouts/footer'); -%> 
  <%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%>

</body>

</html>
```

**header.ejs**

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

Comment: can you include your ejs files that are included in that file?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Syntax` is wrong, just write

```
<%- include ('layouts/navbar.ejs') %>
```

`ejs` doesn't have closing tags like `-%>` and for `ejs` comments you can comment it as `<%# (...) %>` this tag highlights the comments.

Comment: '-%>' is a legit tag and is not the origin of this issue. The dash modifies the closing tag to  "trim following newline" according to documentation for EJS-NPM.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> We use the raw output tag <%- with include
> ```

The above `<%-` has no matching closing tag.

EJS does not parse HTML comments.

Comment: I removed the HTML comment, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @tylerlorenzi — That you have other instances of the error outside of the code you've included in the question.